# Setting Up Amazon aws Credentials for S3 php SDK 3 on a Share Hosting

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am installing Amazon S3 php SDK V3 on a shared hosting.
I have so far done everything the [aws php sdk v3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#credential-profiles) says apart from **where** and **how** to store the credentials

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

The documentation is not clear for me. This is my folder structure

```
home/sample/public_html/ /*index.php the root of my website*/
home/sample/public_html/media/aws/ /*s3 php v3 sdk stored here*/
home/sample/public_html/media/  /*my custom php script for upload stored here*/
```

My problem is basically 1) **WHERE** to store the credentials and 2) **HOW** to store the credentials

I will be glad if anyone can help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the docs link you have posted says where to put these credentials:

> The file should be placed at ~/.aws/credentials, where ~ represents
>   your HOME directory.

With the structure of the file being.

> The format of the AWS credentials file should look something like the
>   following:
>
> [default] aws_access_key_id = YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
>   aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
>
> [project1] aws_access_key_id = ANOTHER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
>   aws_secret_access_key = ANOTHER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY Each section
>   (e.g., [default], [project1]), represents a separate credential
>   profile. Profiles can be referenced from a SDK configuration file, or
>   when you are instantiating a client, using the profile option:

Comment: thank you for your responds.. So in my case based on the file structure i provided which folder will be the home?

Comment: it should be user user home, basically on a linux box just do a `cd` and it should go to to the home dir, and similarly for window box just do a `cd %HOMEPATH%`

Comment: Can I do that on a shared hosting?

Comment: depending on whether you have a separate user on the shared host, you might be able to pull it off. Also there are other ways to pass the creds to teh sdk listed in the doc you might also want to take a look at those.